# Wahoo Kickr Core power cable snapped

Tags: turbo-trainer, wahoo, zwift

So after a few years of a dodgey power cable connection, the cable has finally snapped off. The turbo is perfectly functional otherwise and so I wouldn't want to replace the whole thing.

I was wondering what the intermediate cable (connecting to the kickr) is called and how I would go about replacing it. There are two connecting wires, but I figured that soldering it myself is quite dangerous. I have attached the pictures. [image][image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is low voltage - probably 12 Volts at most.  If you're not comfortable with a soldering iron then any competent electronics hobbiest person could fix this.

You'd bare the four ends, twist the naked wires together being aware to keep the colours the same, solder, then insulate.  Test to make sure its right.

Then your goal is to stop the same damage happening again.  Clearly there's stress on the cable at this point, so you need to secure the cable to the frame or cover or something to stop it flexing right there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have a soldering kit and might give it a go then. Just to confirm, would I need to strip the cable on the adapter side to expose the two wires, twist, and then solder to the correct two wires on the turbo side?

Comment: @iyop45 pretty much yeah.   There's two parts, the fix/repair, and then changing somethign to stop this happening again.   You can't shock yourself off 12V, though the soldering iron does get hot enough to hurt.  Good luck !

Comment: Great it works well! I will insulate it all up properly now. I will say for anyone else with this problem, the outerwire on the adapter side connects to ground/black on the turbo side.